# Set preloader width relative to window, not screen

Tags: css, window, size

Is it possible to set the preloader width relative to the users window, not the screen's width?

The code I'm using:

CSS

```
#_preload_div_ {
    background: url("image/_preloader.gif") no-repeat center center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 75%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999999;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="_preload_div_">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what do you mean but i think you need to use % or you define it more please.

Comment: My GIF is smaller if the browser window is smaller. (Use % on what?)